# Error al recorrer una lista

Tags: java, lista, spring, bucle-for, bucles

tengo un problema al recorrer una lista, cuando ejecuto la consulta obtengo 2 registros, cuando ejecuto la función size tambien obtengo 2 registros, pero cuando intento guardar los 2 registros en la  variable CodPidm, solo aparece un registro.

```
int CodPidm = 0;
            List<Integer> data = jdbcTemplate.queryForList(query, Integer.class);
            System.out.println("data" + data);
            for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println("data size for " + data.size());
                System.out.println("data get(i) " + data.get(i));
                CodPidm = data.get(i);
                listaPIDM.add(CodPidm);
-----------------------more code--------------------
```

Los mensajes outprint me muestra los siguientes.
data[350950, 366940]
data size for 2
data get(i) 350950
listaPIDM [350950]

pero al momento de guardar los 2 registros en la variable CodPidm, solo captura la primera variable y no la segunda. 
Necesito que  CodPidm  me guarde los 2 valores 350950, 366940, xq en la actualidad solo me guarda el primero.
¿Podrías ayudarme con el error o la posible solución?
Muchas gracias

me estoy basando de este ejemplo: pero este ejemplo usa resulset, en cambio yo uso jdbc

```
ResultSet rsValidacion = co2.prepareStatement("SELECT * "
                            + " FROM UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIO_PERSONA p,UTIC.UZGTFORMULARIOS f"
                            + " WHERE p.CODIGO_UZGTFORMULARIOS='" + codF + "'"
                            + " AND p.SPRIDEN_PIDM = '" + pidmP + "'"
                            + " AND f.UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_INICIO >= '" + FECHAINICIO + "'"
                            + " AND f.UZGTFORMULARIOS_FECHA_FIN <= '" + FECHAFIN + "'"
                            + " and p.uzgtformularios_estado_llenado = 'N'"
                    ).executeQuery();
                    while (rsValidacion.next()) {
                        codPIDM = rsValidacion.getInt(1);
                        PIDMvalidacion.add(codPIDM);
```

}

Comment: Por favor traduce tu pregunta

Comment: disculpa ya la traducí,

Comment: usa for para recorrer objetos ```for (Integer dato : data)``` , y agregas el dato ```listaPIDM.add(dato);```

Comment: *pero cuando intento guardar los 2 registros en la variable CodPidm..* No es posible almacenar dos objetos en una misma variable. Deberías de especificar de forma detallada, de cual es el error.

Comment: el for de objetos no me sirvio, me sigue guardando el primer registro, pero el segundo no,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**La variable entera 'CodPidm' solamente admite un único valor.**

Solicitas que los 2 datos se guarden, pero el bucle usado trabaja con un **numero a la vez**, al terminar por completo un ciclo vuelve a empezar, pero ahora, con el siguiente numero.

**Ejemplo**

```
List listEjemplo1 = new ArrayList();
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        //DENTRO DEL BUCLE
        //Aquí agrega el numero usado en este ciclo a la lista
        listEjemplo1.add(i);
        //El resultado en el primer mensaje sera '[0]' porque es el ciclo 0
        //y con cada ciclo consumido aumentara la lista
        System.out.println(listEjemplo1);
    }
    //FUERA DEL BUCLE
    //Pero fuera del bucle se muestra completo '[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]',
    //porque ya termino y agrego TODOS los números usados
    System.out.println(listEjemplo1);
```

En el caso que planteas, una opción es cerrar el bucle antes:

```
for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {   
        System.out.println("data size for " + data.size());
        System.out.println("data get(i) " + data.get(i));
        //CodPidm = data.get(i); <--- Es un paso redundante
        listaPIDM.add(data.get(i)); //<--- Reduces código de esta manera
    }    // <--- Cierra el bucle en este espacio del código
    //Resultado 'listaPIDM[350950, 366940]'
    System.out.println("listaPIDM" + listaPIDM);
//-----------------------more code--------------------
```

Ten en cuenta que al cerrar el bucle el código que este a continuación estará fuera, así que es posible que te sobre una llave y/o que salgan errores en la letra *i* si es que la usaste después.

Comment: Muchas gracias Alexis